# SSO between SharePoint Online and On-Premises .Net Web Applications

Tags: azure, sharepoint, single-sign-on

Is it possible to have Single-Sign On between SharePoint Online and on-premises web application?

For example, once I logged in into SharePoint Online, if I navigate to .Net Web App URL, it will not ask me to login anymore.

Also, from SharePoint Online, can call REST endpoints from .Net Web App and display it in SharePoint Online.

Currently, On-Premises AD is being synced to Azure AD.

Is it simply pointing the .Net Web Application to authenticate against Azure AD instead of on-premises AD?

Answer (score 0):

in SharePoint on-prem You are using NTLM authentication right (to authenticate to local AD)? And in SharePoint Online You are login by OF365 to Azure AD right?

If that is the case You should be using the same authentication provider to have SSO. In SharePoint on-prem You should not use basic authentication and NTLM but custom(form-based) or SAML (Token-based). I tried the second one where we used AD FS (Active Directory Federation Services) which is a separate component that may be installed on one of AD servers. The ADFS allows You to define a custom login page for Your company which will authenticate the user to Your local AD.

After that You can configure SharePoint on-prem to authenticate using ADFS (SAML authentication), You will need to generate a trust between Farm server and ADFS using generated certificate. Please check the [link](https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/sharepoint-2013-configure-web-application-for-adfs/)

Also You will need to configure OF365 to use ADFS authentication. Please check the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/09/09/setup-sharepoint-online-on-premises-single-sign-on-sso/)

I myself never did the ADFS authentication for SharePoint Online, I only did it once for SharePoint on-prem (in the company I did this task the online part was already done) and it required a bit of powershell scripting. Please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/SharePoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/plan-user-authentication#Supported) to get the basic idea for authentications plans You can use.

I know this info is not much.. but it's always some start... I hope it will be helpfull:)